# Visual Basic Datagridview cell event then press keyboard enter

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem and I don't understand how to solve it, if this is possible. I have a datagridview and I want to have a event then into one cell text I entry new line (keyboard enter), I now there are a event "grid_keydown" or "grid_keypress", but this two work only then I select the datagridview full row and not for each datagridview cell. There are a solution to config datagridview properties to work this 2 event also for each datagridview cell editing? Thank you a lot

[image]

Comment: Clarification: You want to add a line break to the text which is present in a cell in your datagrid; this should happen when you press Enter in that specific cell?

Comment: I think so is clearer .. then I press enter then my cursor is in the red rectangle i want to keep a event

Comment: CellBeginEdit event, Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: CellBeginEdit event is calling then I put into the cell the cursor, but then I try to press enter or write something don't go into this event, am so sorry.

Comment: @SilviaParfeni I see that your grid is in german. Do you want to tell me in German what you want to achieve? I still don´t understand 100% ;)

Comment: Is the ReadOnly property set to True?

Comment: ok, Ich versuche zu erklären, aber ich spreche nict so gut Deutsch. Ich mochte ein Ereignis(event) haben, wenn in Beschreibung cell ein neu linie hinzufugen (mit anderen Worten, wenn Sie die Eingabetaste drücken) Danke schön.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to achieve what you are looking for. The bad news: It´s more tricky than I thought (and should be imho). Anyway you need the following steps:

1. Create a custom `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` class.
   It is to override the default behavior that the `Enter` key accepts the changes in the `Cell` and switches to the next row. It also attaches a `NewLine` to the current cell text.

   ```
   Public Class MyDatagridTextBoxEditControl
      Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl

     Public Overrides Function EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData As Keys, dataGridViewWantsInputKey As Boolean) As Boolean
        If dataGridViewWantsInputKey AndAlso keyData = Keys.Enter Then
            AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
            Return MyBase.EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData, False)
       End If 
       Return MyBase.EditingControlWantsInputKey(keyData, dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
     End Function
   End Class
   ```
2. Create a custom `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` class.
   It is to set and use the previously created `DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl` type.

   ```
   Public Class MyDatagridTextBoxCell
      Inherits DataGridViewTextBoxCell

      Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EditType As Type
         Get
             Return GetType(MyDatagridTextBoxEditControl)
         End Get
      End Property
   End Class
   ```
3. Bind the data together inr the `DataGridView`.
   For my example I put the code into the Form´s constructor (after
   `InitializeComponent()`), but you can also put it into the `Load`
   event

   ```
   'Assume [Beschreibung] is column no. 5
   DataGridView1.Columns.Item(4).CellTemplate = New MyDatagridTextBoxCell()
   ```

(Depending on where you put this code you might need to call `DataGridVie1.Refresh()`).

**Remarks**: This code will lead to that you are not able to accept the changed value in the text cell with the `Enter` key anymore. It will however accept the input when you left mouseclick outside the cell. A `Esc` keypress will still revert the text changes.
You might add code into `EditingControlWantsInputKey` which treats another key like `Enter`, e.g. `Insert` or similar.

Without this code you can achieve the same behavior with the key combination `Shift + Enter`

Comment: I think, I can put the the point 3 then I click into my column needed cell, I try to do this tomorrow. thank you